# relative positioning and font sizing in flex

Tags: apache-flex, css-position

I need to position an object in the bottom half of a container (working on flex 4)- abt 25% above the bottom...and cant use x,y coordinates given need for resizing. I have been able to position the layout containers and they work well

Also need fonts to resize as the buttons get smaller

Appreciate your guidance in advance

Comment: Did you have any questions?  Perhaps you should share some code and describe the issues you are having to accomplish these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pastebin.com/7VivyqH5

Comment: thanks... i am able to get the coordinates also on rleative basis 

somehow am having trouble with font resizing- but logic is clear